# Force Hibernate to always use default no args constructor even when select parameters are specified

Tags: java, spring, performance, hibernate

A bit of context first - I'm implementing an API where the requests contain fields that the client is interested in, basically parameters to select directly. Because the overall size of data is quite large when not limited this way, it's an obvious performance benefit to do so both when it comes to serializing and transmitting the data, as well as limiting the amount of data retrieved from the database. Therefore I'm attempting to pass those to select when doing a database query.

The issue I'm facing is that when doing a query with select, Hibernate expects specific constructor to exist that corresponds to the select parameters. For example, if I specify that I'm only interested in `id` (long) and `model` (String) columns in my `BasicInfo` class, then Hibternate attempts to find and call `BasicInfo(int, String)` constructor. This is indicated by the error message I'm getting:

> org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Unable to locate
>   appropriate constructor on class
>   [my.package.BasicInfo]. Expected arguments
>   are: long, java.lang.String [select new
>   my.package.BasicInfo(generatedAlias0.id,
>   generatedAlias0.model) from
>   my.package.BasicInfo as generatedAlias0]

This is not an option for me. The client may wish to ask for let's say `model` (String) and `serial` (also a String) in one request in this order, while another client may wish to ask for the same fields in reverse order. Because I'd only be able to create one combination of `BasicInfo(String, String)` constructor, one of the requests is going to retrieve data in reversed oder. Even omitting this fact, I'd have to create all possible constructor permutations of all possible fields that may be requested which - with the number of fields that exist in this class - makes it very inefficient, if not impossible thing to do.

What I'm looking for is a way to force Hibernate to use a default class constructor even when select query parameter is specified and use setters to set the requested fields. If not that, then maybe another way that would allow me to not retrieve full row data from the database when each request is made (and then limiting it in the application code before sending back to the client).

I've also tried to register a custom Hibernate interceptor and overriding its `instantiate` method like so:

```
public class CustomInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {

    @Override
    public Object instantiate(String entityName, EntityMode entityMode, Serializable id) {
        if(entityName.equals(BasicInfo.class.getName()))
            return new BasicInfo();
        return null;
    }

}
```

hoping that this would change the object creation strategy. In this case when I don't specify select parameters, this method is correctly invoked. However when select parameters are given, it is *not* called at all and Hibternate attempts to directly call constructor with specific arguments instead.

Below are relevant portions of the project:

Code setting select parameters (irrelevant parts of code removed for clarity):

```
CriteriaQuery<T> query = cb.createQuery(responseClass);
Root<T> from = query.from(responseClass);
// Handle select
CriteriaQuery<T> select = null;
if(request.getSelect() != null) {
    List<Selection<?>> selectionList = new ArrayList<Selection<?>>();
    for(String s : request.getSelect()) {
        selectionList.add(from.get(s));
    }
    select = query.multiselect(selectionList);
} else {
    // select all fields
    select = query.select(from);
}
TypedQuery<T> typedQuery = em.createQuery(select);      
List<T> itemsList = typedQuery.getResultList();
```

And `applicaion.yml`:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    platform: h2
    driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create-drop
    show-sql: true
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the older interface and get the result set as `List<Object[]>` simply by using `setProjection(myProjectionList)`. An `Object[]` is not what you want, but converting it to `Map<String, Object>` is a one-liner and after the conversion to JSON you may see the same thing like with your incomplete object.

Not sure if it works in your case and whether it applies to JPA2 or whatever you're using.

If you insist on objects, you may create them yourself, possibly by copying the field to its "right" positions and then calling `new BasicInfo(myRearangedArray)` where the constructor finds each member on a fixed position. AFAIK that's what hibernate does when it gets the full entity, so you may use its code and save yourself writing the constructor.